# Android libGDX: сборка iOs приложения

Tags: ios, libgdx

У меня есть приложение которое использует libGDX. Написал я его пару лет назад, и сейчас мне требуется его пересобрать, но у меня не выходит. При выборе create Ipa, я не могу указать сертификат, поле, которое используется для указания сертификата, пустое. Я не совсем понимаю как мне указать сертификат, его из apple developers console Я получил.
[image: поле есть, но его отредактировать нельзя, и оно пустое]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это libGDX проект, нужно было собрать iOS часть xCode'ом, а значит для этого нежен xCode, запустил xCode'ом проект, выполнил"некоторые" действия (уже не помню какие, там что-то очевидное) и "Signing identity" - появился.